# What's the difference between java and python socket when send bytearrays

Tags: java, python, sockets

There is a server which coding in java.I got it's api docs and make a java  client:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws WindException,   SendException, RecvException{
String host="172.22.128.16";
int port=6001;
TcpComm tcp = new TcpComm(true);
try {
    tcp.call(host,port);
    tcp.setTimeOut(30);
    String msg="POF001|S2B024|01|0033596105||";
    byte[] req = msg.getBytes();
    tcp.sendMsg(req);
    byte[] ans = tcp.recvBytesMsg();
    System.out.println(ans);
} catch (CallException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

My sendMsg method is send an bytearray with a special head which represents the contents' length and content:

```
public void sendMsg(byte[] b) throws SendException {
        try {
            OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream();
            if (hasAtrHead) {
                byte[] sbt = short2Byte((short) b.length, true);
                out.write(head);
                out.write(sbt);
            }
            out.write(b);
            out.flush();
        }
```

My head method:

```
static public byte[] short2Byte(short value, boolean order) {
        byte[] bt = new byte[2];
        if (order) { // true 高8位 存放在tb[0]
            bt[0] = (byte) (value >> 8 & 0xff);
            bt[1] = (byte) (value & 0xff);
        } else {
            bt[1] = (byte) (value >> 8 & 0xff);
            bt[0] = (byte) (value & 0xff);
        }
        return bt;
    }
```

And all my java client runs well,but when i turned to a python client,i can't send contents to server cause likely to be filtered.My python client:

```
#-*- coding:GBK -*-
import socket
class Comm(object):
    def heads(self,length):
        bt=bytearray()
        bt.append(length >> 8 & 0xff)
        bt.append(length & 0xff)
        return bt
    def client(self):
        HOST='172.22.128.16'
        PORT=6001
        s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((HOST,PORT))       
        while 1:
            content='POF001|F2B107|01|3061009458||'
            length=len(content)
            head=self.heads(length)
            content=bytearray(content)
            s.send(head)
            s.send(content)
            data=s.recv(2048)    
        s.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    a=Comm()
    a.client()
```

So can anyone tells me what's the difference between my java client and python client?Thanks very much!!!

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look around and take the [tour], and read through the [help center]. You can also read about [ask] a good question.

Comment: *There is a server which coding in java.I got it's api docs and make java a client:* - And then ... surely something negative or questionable happens or else you wouldn't have a question.

Comment: yeah,surely I got some errors,and I am stuck with it a few days.I will appreciate it  if you could help me solve this problem,thanks for your reply.